# How to use Regasm.exe to register a COMl for an ASCOM project

Tags: dll, ascom

I am trying to build a simple solution but always get the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The assembly 'ASCOM.DeviceInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=565de7938946fba7' is not registered for COM Interop. Please register it with regasm.exe /tlb.    ASCOM.ML16200.DeviceClass1
Error       The assembly "C:\Users\tonyb\source\repos\ASCOM.ML16200.DeviceClass1\ASCOM.ML16200.DeviceClass1\bin\Debug\ASCOM.ML16200.Camera.dll" could not be converted to a type library. Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'ASCOM.ML16200.Camera, ASCOM.ML16200.Camera'. Error: Error loading type library/DLL.  ASCOM.ML16200.DeviceClass1

I've tried using the following command within Visual Studio Powershell, but it always fails:

PS C:\Users\tonyb\source\repos\ASCOM.ML16200.DeviceClass1> **regasm.exe ASCOM.ML16200.Camera.dll /tlb**
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.8.4084.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.4084.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

RegAsm : error RA0000 : Unable to locate input assembly 'ASCOM.ML16200.Camera.dll' or one of its dependencies.
PS C:\Users\tonyb\source\repos\ASCOM.ML16200.DeviceClass1>

Can anyone please tell me how to properly register this .dll?

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that this will help you:

**1. Run Visual Studio as an administrator. And try to rebuild the project, then start debugging (so Visual Studio will try to register the .dll file).** This method worked for me on Visual Studio 2015.

But when developing a driver for Focuser in Visual Studio 2019, this method did not work for me.

[My screenshot Focuser error registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvwF2.jpg)

**2. Registering ASCOM .dll file in manual mode:**

- Open [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) as Administrator
- Now using the [regasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool) tool, register the .dll file

[My screenshot example, manual register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM8H2.jpg)

- Now you can start debugging the .dll file.

*P.S.
Do not forget, you cannot debug .dll files directly, use other applications for this. For example ASCOM provides ready-made templates for such applications*